# How to get cookies from urllib.request?

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, urllib

How to get cookie from an `urllib.request`?

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    'user': 'user',
    'pass': 'pass'
})
data = data.encode('utf-8')

request = urllib.request.urlopen('http://example.com', data)
print(request.info())
```

`request.info()` returns cookies but not in very usable way.

Comment: What is a "usable" way?

Comment: you named `request` but that's a `response` object. The question is vague and could be solved in many different ways, but we don't know what are you trying to achieve (thus the "what is a usuable way?")

Answer (score 6):

`response.info()` is a `dict` type object. so you can parse any info you need. Here is a demo written in python3:

```
from urllib import request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

# declare url, header_params 

req = request.Request(url, data=None, headers=header_params, method='GET')
try:
    response = request.urlopen(req)

    cookie = response.info().get_all('Set-Cookie')
    content_type = response.info()['Content-Type']
except HTTPError as err:
    print("err status: {0}".format(err))
    return
```

You can now, parse `cookie` variable as your application requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just used the following code to get cookie from [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/) #17, hope it helps (Python 3.8 being used):

```
import http.cookiejar
import urllib

cookiejar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
cookieproc = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieproc)
response = opener.open(url)
for cookie in cookiejar:
    print(cookie.name, cookie.value)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package is a much better choice these days. Try this sample code that shows google setting cookies when you visit:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.google.com"
r = requests.get(url,timeout=5)
if r.status_code == 200:
    for cookie in r.cookies:
        print(cookie)            # Use "print cookie" if you use Python 2.
```

Gives:

```
Cookie NID=67=n0l3ME1Jl3-wwlH7oE5pvxJ_CfU12hT5Kh65wh21bvE3hrKFAo1sJVj_UcuLCr76Ubi3yxENROaYNEitdgW4IttL43YZGlf8xAPl1IbzoLG31KP5U2tiP2y4DzVOJ2fA for .google.se/

Cookie PREF=ID=ce66d1288fc0d977:FF=0:TM=1407525509:LM=1407525509:S=LxQv7q8fju-iHJPZ for .google.se/
```

Comment: I voted this down as it didn't answer the question - its good advice but not the answer.

Comment: I agree, there is no answer here.